# How to get value from java object?

Tags: java, object, wso2

```java
public boolean mediate(MessageContext synCtx) {
    Object obj = synCtx.getProperty("RequestPayload");       
    System.out.println(obj);        
    return true;
}
```

From above code I can see output like below.

```json
{
    "name" : "Jone",
    "marks" : "45"
}
```

Can I know how I print name from that object.
I tried like below but its not working.

```java
System.out.println(obj.get("name").toString());
```

Can anyone help me I am new to this.

Comment: You need to convert your string first to an object that contains name and marks attributes using Json converters. There are many...

Comment: @YoucefLaidani What are you trying to do here? Can you explain your full use case?

Comment: @ycr I mean create a class that has a name and marks attributes, then use for example ObjectMapper to convert the JSON to this type, so after you can use `myObj.getName()`

Comment: I mean what is your real business use case? If you just need the name and marks in your Class mediator why don't you just pass the two as separate properties to the class mediator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `obj` is a JSON string. You will need to use a library like GSON (https://github.com/google/gson) to parse it, either to another object or to a map.

Examples for map:

```java
class Main {
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext synCtx) {
        String obj = synCtx.getProperty("RequestPayload").toString();       
        Map<String, Object> result = gson.fromJson(obj, Map.class);
        System.out.println(result.get("name"));        
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As written you're still trying to call `.get("name")` on a string which won't work.

Comment: I have amended my example